# Function that will read strings of time from a .srt file and change it

Tags: c++

I am working on a very simple program, which will receive the name of a file and a number (how much you want to delay your subtitles for from that file), then save that file as another file with delayed time. My question here is how to write a function that will change the time.

Let's say that the file looks like that:

1
00:00:49,100 --> 00:00:52,515
- Everything in place?
- You shouldn't have replaced me.

2
00:00:52,770 --> 00:00:55,391
I know, but I wanted to take your shift.

3
00:00:55,940 --> 00:00:58,312
You like him, don't you? You like watching him

4
00:00:58,568 --> 00:01:01,569
- Don't be ridicolous!
- We are going to kill him. Understand?

5
00:01:01,822 --> 00:01:04,313
Morpheus believes, that he's The One.

...and so on. So how could one do that?

Comment: If it is your first encounter with programming and you have completely no idea what you are about to do I'd rather suggest `c#` or `Java`, these languages in my opinion are easier, to dive into programming, than `c++`. Your general idea is good, but we won't write code for you, Make some effort start coding and if you get stuck ask some less broad question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it comes to `c#` I would start of with making two **Classes** `srtFile` and `srtDialogue`

Grab copy of **SharpDevelop**, google for '**word in bold** c#' and you should have some good spin off.

> srtFile

would contain **fields**

- **array** or **list** with **type** of `srtDialogue` with all dialogs from file made into separate `srtDialogue` **objects**
- **string** that contains processed file name

would contain **methods**

- To **load file** and transform its content into `srtDialogue` **objects**
- To **save file** - here and with load you that **loop** you were talking about
- To shift time, here some **overloaded method** would be maybe necessary/helpful

and whatever you will see as missing or necessary

> srtDialogue

would contain **fields**

- **int** integer with number of dialogue
- **timestamp** start timestamp
- **timestamp** end timestamp
- **array** or **list** with **type** of **string** with all text lines of single dialogue block
- **string** that contains unprocessed dialogue block from srt

would contain **methods**

- To **parse** dialogue block text to numbers time stamps and assigns part of **string** to fields in `srtDialogue`
- To put together fields of `srtDialogue` into text that can be recieved by save method in `srtFile`
- To shift time of `srtDialogue` itself, here some **overloaded method** would be maybe necessary/helpful

and whatever you will see as missing or necessary

And that's pretty much it, rest is up to you!